# 2 arrays to serialize

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, json, serialization

I have the following code which works well:

```
Dim dept As New ArrayList
Dim forename As New ArrayList

objJSONStringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
objSQLConnection = New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("connString"))

objSQLCommand = New SqlCommand("select dept, forename from table1", objSQLConnection)

objSQLCommand.Connection.Open()
objSQLDataReader = objSQLCommand.ExecuteReader()

While objSQLDataReader.Read()
    dept.Add(New With {Key .dept = objSQLDataReader("dept")})
    forename.Add(New With {Key .forename = objSQLDataReader("forename")})
End While

objSQLDataReader.Close()
objSQLCommand.Connection.Close()

Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim arrayJson As String = serializer.Serialize(dept)

Return arrayJson
```

Which gives me:

```
[
    {
        "dept": "dept1"
    },
    {
        "dept": "dept2"
    },
    {
        "dept": "dept3"
    }
]
```

How do I add the second column `forename` in the json data too so it returns:

```
[
    {
        "dept": "dept1",
        "forename": "adam"
    },
    {
        "dept": "dept2",
        "forename": "joe"
    },
    {
        "dept": "dept3",
        "forename": "smith"
    }
]
```

Eventually, I will want to add more columns, i.e. surname.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make a single object with two properties:

```
dept.Add(New With {Key .dept = objSQLDataReader("dept"), .forename = objSQLDataReader("forename")})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you storing the dept and forename of the same table/object in different lists? I think the best way you could go about this is creating an object that represents the 'table1' like so:

```
public class Table1Object {
    public string Dept { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
}
```

and then in your loop through data reader do it like this:

```
List<Table1Object> table1List = new List<Table1Object>()

while (objSQLDataReader.Read())
{
    table1List.Add(new Table1Object 
                       { 
                           Dept = objSQLDataReader("dept"), 
                           Forename = objSQLDataReader("forename") 
                       });
}
```

After that

```
string arrayJson = serializer.Serialize(table1List)
```

Should give you the desired json

PS. My VB is a little rusty, but if I made any mistakes in the code, I hope you get the gist of it :)

Comment: Please convert this into standard C#, that will be easier for me to convert to VB.NET.  Thanks.